# Как правильно настроить UITapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: xcode, objective-c, ios, iphone

Как настроить UITapGestureRecognizer чтобы он не обрабатывал область таб бара?
Т.к. при UITapGestureRecognizer и didSelectItem происходит конфликт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Использовать делегат UIGestureRecognizer

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer
*)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) {

        return NO; // если тач на потомке UIControl не использовать, почему UIControl тк сами кнопки там бара это UITabBarButton приватный подкласс UIControl.  
}
    return YES;
}
```

2 Вариант добавлять на правильный UIVIew свой UITapGestureRecognizer

ЗЫ. блин кошмар как код то нормально отформатировать(

Comment: да, я так и сделал:)
лови плюсы себе в карму)